# Non-null assertion operator for generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The following code:

```
type A = number | undefined
type B<C extends number> = C
let a: B<A>;
```

will give me the error:

`Type 'A' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

---

Is it possible to assume that A will be defined, something like:

```
let a: B<A!>
// or
let a: B<NonNullable<A>>
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This non-null assertion operator is meant to be used for `javascript` variables. Use it for TypeScript types is basically makes no sense.

I'm pretty sure your issue is coming from another place that is forcing you to act that way and which you need to solve instead.

Anyway, if you would like to resolve this quickly, you might need to use the `Exclude` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion).

**Complete solution:**

```js
type A = number | undefined
type B<C extends number> = C
const a: B<Exclude<A, undefined>> = 234;
```